# Ignoring errors in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

In RxSwift I can ignore errors like
`.catchError { _ in Observable.never() }`

Why does this not work in combine (eg. it still completes)
`.catch { _ in Empty(completeImmediately: false) }`

```
struct SimpleError: Error {}
let numbers = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6]
let cancellable = numbers.publisher
    .tryFilter { int -> Bool in
        guard int != 0 else {throw SimpleError()}
        return true
    }
    .catch { _ in Empty(completeImmediately: false) }
    .sink {
        print("\($0)")
    }
```

finishes on the throw. The output is:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: No, `.catch { _ in Empty(completeImmediately: false) }` does not complete. Show more actual context and explain why you think it does.

Comment: Have added an example

Comment: You've confused yourself by putting the `.print()` upstream. The throw does cancel upstream, but the `.catch` does in fact prevent the error from flowing downstream.

Comment: I don't believe so - (edit again to remove the `.print()`, I didn't mean to leave it in). It does complete when the error occurs.

Comment: No, it just stops. Complete would mean the arrival of a `finished` completion. You've prevented that from happening (though you are still not testing correctly to discover that). But as I said, the throw cancels the upstream; that's _why_ it stops. A publisher that has emitted an error is dead, and so is the pipeline upstream from it.

Comment: The way to prevent that is to confine the cancellation to a subpipeline produced with `.flatMap`. That way it can’t percolate up to the publisher.

Comment: Ah ok, cheers. Makes sense - a little different to RxSwift here. Will give that a go

Comment: Example in my book: http://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html#SECfailingwithoutterminating

Comment: Thanks matt - that actually helped a lot. I was trying to simplify my problem in my question (which was probably the wrong approach here) but in my real code I had the .catch _outside_ my flatmap which is why it was stopping. Moving it _inside_ the flatmap fixes it.

Comment: Yup, that’s the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad someone was able to help you in the comments, because you are asking why your code completes when it clearly doesn't.

```
struct SimpleError: Error {}
let numbers = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6]
let cancellable = numbers.publisher
    .tryFilter { int -> Bool in
        guard int != 0 else {throw SimpleError()}
        return true
    }
    .catch { _ in Empty(completeImmediately: false) }
    .print("")
    .sink { _ in }
```

The above clearly does not emit a "finished" event. If you change `completeImmediately` to `true`, then you will see that it does.

Comment: Yep - I was super unclear in my question in an attempt to simplify it. I didn't want the cancellable to stop, which it does when it throws the error. It my real code (not shown) it was because my catch was outside a flatmap instead of inside it.. something that's caught me out in RxSwift before too! Thanks Daniel.

Comment: Weird, when I put this in playground, it still stops after "1". Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the answer a bit:

```
struct SimpleError: Error {}
let numbers = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6]
let cancellable = numbers.publisher
    .map { (value) -> Result<Int, Error> in
        Result {
            guard value != 0 else {
                throw SimpleError()
            }
            return value
        }
    }
    .sink { result in
        switch result {
        case .success (let value):
            print ("\(value)")
        case .failure(let error):
            break
        }
    }
```

This has two benefits:

- The stream does not stop, it keeps publishing
- The error is not lost; it could be examined, displayed or processed if desired